# Mobile Operating System Releases/Updates

Tags: mobile

Is there any Page which collects all Data about Future / Past Releases or Updates to Mobile Operating Systems ?
If not, do exist a Page for specific OS's ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm sure if you go to the Operating Systems website they'll have things like recent changes and changelogs.

I don't know of one place that has it for all of them. for popular mobile systems i check news websites like androidcentral.com or crackberry.com, there are links of both these sites for new on android, blackberry, iphone, nokia and windows phone. they often do reviews and reports on new os releases and discuss the changes that have been made.

But for a deeper look i would check the website for that operating system, thats were you'll find the information needed.

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly what you're looking for, perhaps, but this is something that might be of partial relevance

http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/f/f7/Mobile_os.png

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mobile_operating_system#Mobile_OS_comparison